# "VM Exception while processing transaction: revert" in Truffle test and Truffle dev

Tags: truffle, tokens, erc-20, crowdsale, ganache-cli

this is my problem :)

### Issue

"Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert" when reaching the Transfer function. I think it is related to the fact that my Crowdsale smart contrat hasn't any TotalSupply of my tokens.

### Steps to Reproduce

Token Smart contract :

```js
    pragma solidity   0.5.16; 

    import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/DetailedERC20.sol";
    import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/PausableToken.sol";

    contract TokenSPC is PausableToken, DetailedERC20 
    {

        constructor(string memory _name, string memory _symbol, uint8 _decimals, uint256 _amount)
        DetailedERC20(_name, _symbol, _decimals)
        public
        {

            require(_amount > 0, "amount has to be greater than 0");
            totalSupply_ = _amount.mul(10 ** uint256(_decimals));
            balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply_;
            emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, totalSupply_);


        }
    }
```

Crowdsale Smart Contract :

```js
    pragma solidity 0.5.16;

    import './TokenSPC.sol';
    import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
    import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/PausableToken.sol";
    import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol";
    import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/validation/CappedCrowdsale.sol";


    contract TokenCrowdsale is Crowdsale, CappedCrowdsale {

      //Minim invest contrib
      //Max invest contrib
      uint256 public investorMinCap = 2000000000000000;
      uint256 public investorHardCap = 50000000000000000000;
      mapping(address => uint256) public contributions;

      constructor(
        uint256 _rate,
        address payable _wallet,
        ERC20 _token,
        uint256 _cap
       )
      Crowdsale(_rate, _wallet, _token)
      CappedCrowdsale(_cap)
      public
      {

      }

      function getUserContribution(address _beneficiary)
      public view returns(uint256)
      {
        return contributions[_beneficiary];
      }

      function _preValidatePurchase(
        address _beneficiary, 
        uint256 _weiAmount
     )
     internal
     {
        super._preValidatePurchase(_beneficiary,_weiAmount);
        uint256 _existingContribution = contributions[_beneficiary];
        uint256 _newContribution = _existingContribution.add(_weiAmount);
        require(_newContribution >= investorMinCap && _newContribution <= investorHardCap);
        contributions[_beneficiary] = _newContribution;
     } 
   }
```

Test Crowdsale.test :

```js
import ether from './helpers/ether';
import sendTransaction from './helpers/sendTransaction';
import EVMRevert from './helpers/EVMRevert';

const BN = web3.utils.BN;

require('chai')
  .use(require('chai-as-promised'))
  .use(require('chai-bn')(BN))
  .should();

const Token = artifacts.require('TokenSPC');
const TokenCrowdsale = artifacts.require('TokenCrowdsale');

contract('TokenCrowdsale', function([_, wallet, investor1, investor2]) {

  /*before(async function() {
    // Transfer extra ether to investor1's account for testing
    await web3.eth.sendTransaction({ from: _, to: investor1, value: ether(60) })
    await web3.eth.sendTransaction({ from: _, to: investor2, value: ether(20) })
  });*/

  beforeEach(async function () {
    // Token config
    this.name = "Seed Project Coin";
    this.symbol = "SPC";
    this.decimals = 18;
    this.amount = 380000000;


    // Deploy Token
    this.token = await Token.new(
      this.name,
      this.symbol,
      this.decimals,
      this.amount
    );

    // Crowdsale config
    this.rate = new BN(500);
    this.wallet = wallet;
    this.cap = ether(100);

    //Invest cap
    this.investorMinCap = ether(0.002);
    this.investorHardCap = ether(50);

    this.crowdsale = await TokenCrowdsale.new(
      this.rate,
      this.wallet,
      this.token.address,
      this.cap


    );

    // Transfer token owern to crowdsale
    await this.token.transferOwnership(this.crowdsale.address);


  });

  describe('token', function() {
    it("should check totalSupply", async function() {
      const _supp = await this.token.totalSupply();
      console.log( "     ", "totalSupply =", _supp.toString());
    });

  });

  describe('crowdsale', function() {
    it('tracks the rate', async function() {
      const _rate = await this.crowdsale.rate();
      //console.log( "     ", "Rate =", _rate );
      //console.log( "     ", "this.rate =", this.rate );
      _rate.should.be.a.bignumber.that.equals(this.rate);
    });

    it('tracks the wallet', async function() {
      const wallet = await this.crowdsale.wallet();
      wallet.should.equal(this.wallet);
    });

    it('tracks the token', async function() {
      const token = await this.crowdsale.token();
      token.should.equal(this.token.address);
    });
  });

  //A revoir---------------------------------------------
 /* describe('actualization crowdsale', function() {
    it('actualize total supply of crowdsale after purchase', async function() {
      const originalTotalSupply = await this.token.totalSupply();
      this.token.totalSupply_ -= 1;
      const newTotalSupply = await this.token.totalSupply();
      assert.isTrue(newTotalSupply < originalTotalSupply)
    });
  });*/

  describe('capped crowdsale', async function() {
    it('has the correct hard cap', async function() {
      const _cap = await this.crowdsale.cap();
      _cap.should.be.a.bignumber.that.equals(this.cap);
    });
  });

  //A revoir ---------------------------------------------
  /*describe('accepting payments', function() {
    it('should accept payments', async function() {
      const value = ether(1);
      const purchaser = investor2;
      await this.crowdsale.sendTransaction({ value : value, from : investor1}).should.be.fulfilled;
      await this.crowdsale.buyTokens(investor1, { value: value, from: purchaser }).should.be.fulfilled;
    });
  });*/

  describe('buyTokens()', function() {
    describe('when the contrib is less than min cap', function(){
      it('rejects the transaction', async function() {
        const value = this.investorMinCap - 1;
        await this.crowdsale.buyTokens(investor2, { value: value, from: investor2 }).should.be.rejectedWith(EVMRevert);
      });
    });

     describe('when the invest has already met the min cap', function(){
      it('allows the invest to contrib below the min cap', async function() {
        //isvalid
        const value1 = ether(1);


        await this.crowdsale.buyTokens(investor1, { value: value1, from: investor1 });
        console.log( "     ", "inv =", investor1 );
        console.log( "     ", "value =", value1 );
        console.log( "     ", "inv.value =", await this.crowdsale.buyTokens(investor1, { value: value1, from: investor1 }) );
        //is less then invest cap
        const value2 = 1; //wei
        await this.crowdsale.buyTokens(investor1, { value: value2, from: investor1 }).should.be.fulfilled;

      });
    });

  });

/*---------------A revoir
  describe('when the total contrib exceed the invest hardcap', function(){
    it('reject the transaction', async function() {
      //first contrib in valid range
      const value1 = ether(2);
      await this.crowdsale.buyTokens(investor1, { value: value1, from: investor1});

      //second is over hardcap
      const value2 = ether(49);
      await this.crowdsale.buyTokens(investor1, { value: value2, from: investor1}).should.be.rejectedWith(EVMRevert);
    });
  });

  describe('when the contrib is within the valid range', function() {
    const value = ether(2);
    it('succeeds & updates the contrib amount', async function() {
      await this.crowdsale.buyTokens(investor2, { value: value, from: investor2 }).should.be.fulfilled;
      const contribution = await this.crowdsale.getUserContribution(investor2);
      contribution.should.be.bignumber.equals;
    });
  });
*/

});
```

Deployement script :

```js
const Token = artifacts.require("./TokenSPC.sol");
const TokenCrowdsale = artifacts.require("./TokenCrowdsale.sol");

const ether = (n) => new web3.utils.BN(web3.utils.toWei(n.toString(), 'ether'));

const duration = {
  seconds: function (val) { return val; },
  minutes: function (val) { return val * this.seconds(60); },
  hours: function (val) { return val * this.minutes(60); },
  days: function (val) { return val * this.hours(24); },
  weeks: function (val) { return val * this.days(7); },
  years: function (val) { return val * this.days(365); },
};

module.exports = async function(deployer, network, accounts) {
  const _name = "Seed Project Coin";
  const _symbol = "SPC";
  const _decimals = 18;
  const _amount = 380000000;

  await deployer.deploy(Token , _name, _symbol, _decimals, _amount );
  const deployedToken = await Token.deployed();



  const _rate           = 1;
  const _wallet         = accounts[0]; // TODO: Replace me
  const _token          = deployedToken.address;
  const _cap            = ether(100);

  await deployer.deploy(
    TokenCrowdsale,
    _rate,
    _wallet,
    _token,
    _cap

  );

  return true;
};
```

**First method to have the error :**

Launch ganache-cli via cmd : `ganache-cli`

Compile : `truffle compile`

Launch test : `truffle test ./test/TokenCrowdsale.test.js`

**Second method to have the error :**

Launch ganache-cli via cmd : `ganache-cli`

Compile : `truffle compile`

Migrate : `truffle migrate`

Use console : `truffle console`

Commands in truffle console :

```
    - TokenSPC.deployed().then(instance => token = instance)
    - TokenCrowdsale.deployed().then(instance => crowdsale = instance)

    - web3.eth.getAccounts().then(function(acc){ accounts = acc }) 
    -  var tokenamount = 100 * 10**18 
    - token.transfer(accounts[1], tokenamount.toString())

    - crowdsale.buyTokens(accounts[1], { from: accounts[1], value: 10000000000000000000 })
```

### Expected Behavior

The Crowdsale smart contract have a fixed totalSupply, i don't want any minted token. So i expect the crowdsale to do the transactions to buy the token and transfer it to the user.

### Actual Results

[image: 2]

---

[image: 1]

---

[image: Sans titre]

### Environment

- Operating System: Windows 10
- Ethereum client: Ganache-cli => v6.9.1, Ganache-core => v2.10.2
- Truffle version (`truffle version`): v5.1.20
- node version (`node --version`): v12.16.1
- npm version (`npm --version`): v6.13.4

### More Informations

I'm following a tutorial from DappUniversity : Real World Ico to help me building my smart contract functionnalities. I've done a lot of research about a lot of errors that i've encountered and almost find everytime a solution. But the VM Error is crap and doesn't tell anything. Also, i didn't find any issue similar to mine. There's only one topic pointing out the fact that most of the time if it's not out-of-gas issue, it's because we don't have any token to buy, and that's true for my part. I really think it's because i don't have any totalSupply in my crowdsale so he can't buy / transfer / ect... and i'm stuck because i can't find a tutorial or topic explaing how to have a fixed total supply. Actually there is one really sticking to my situation which is that topic :

[Crowdsale Tokens](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/34620/crowdsale-tokens)

But he is creating the token contract with the help of the crowdsale contract, and i'm not doing this neither i want to. I need to find a way to transfer the totalSupply from the token contract to the crowdsale contract, and to test it with truffle test.

Thanks a lot for your help peeps !

Answer (score 0):

Your crowdsale contract has no tokens to transfer to the buyer.

You transfer ownership of the Token **Contract** in your test file, but the **total supply** is still in control of the Token Contract deployer address . From the looks of it should be your account[0].

After both your contract have been instantiated, you will need to do something like:

`await this.token.transfer(desiredAmountOfTokens, this.crowdsale.address)`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i’m pretty sure it comes from the fact that my Crowdsale contract have no supply has you said. I was expecting to do the transfer from the Token.sol Smartcontract, but in fact, i need to do it in the Test script ? So i can’t make it an automatism ? I will need to transfer manually the supply from the token to the crowdsale after their deployments ?

Thank you really much for your time !